# TestNG @Factory annotation + not enough knowledge on Dependency Injection

Tags: java, testng

I am just learning dependency injection and I dont get its logic at all. Not to mention, TestNG's requirements are always too bizarre for me.

I have this class that provides the data, and a test class that needs it:

```
public abstract class AppData { // extends Mailer

    @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
    public static Object[][] setUp() throws Exception {


        //prepare the data here - code.

        //pass the data to the test case
        Object[][] setUp = new Object[1][4];
        setUp[0][0] = driver;
        setUp[0][1] = wait;
        setUp[0][2] = array;
        setUp[0][3] = array2;   
        return setUp;
    }
}
```

and this is the test class

```
public class AppTest { 

//this is my attempt to make a dependency injection, completely blindly shooting in the dark
    private AppData appdata;

    public AppTest (
            AppData appdata
        ) {
           this.appdata = appdata;
        }



@Factory(dataProviderClass=com.fmydomain.tests.AppData.class,dataProvider="dataProvider")
    public void oneUserTwoUser(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

and Im getting this error when I run it:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The factory method class com.f1rstt.tests.AppTest3.oneUserTwoUser() threw an exception
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:93)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:140)
```

EDIT: I have also tried the following way:

```
public class AppTest3 { 

    private AppData appdata = new AppData();

    public AppTest3(AppData appdata) {
        this.appdata = appdata;
    }

    WebDriver driver = AppData.driver;
    WebDriverWait wait = AppData.wait;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = AppData.array;
    //ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2 = AppData.array2;

    @Parameters({ "driver", "wait", "array" })
    @Test
    public void oneUserTwoUser(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) throws Exception {
```

but I get this error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'driver' is required by @Test on method oneUserTwoUser but has not been marked @Optional or defined
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Spring for DI?

Comment: I dont know what Spring or DI means. @assylias sorry, I edited the question now.

Comment: @J.Kowalski DI=Dependency Injection / Spring=a DI framework. I have removed the DI tag which is a little confusing in this context.

Comment: Have you tried to include the `setup` method to your `AppTest` class directly?

Comment: Well, Im not using DI. I just found some code on the internet and tried to implement DI, but I have this problem with TestNG...

Comment: @assylias how can I include the setup method directly? I want it to be out of this class, in the AppData class (because I use it in lots of classes later on)

Comment: @J.Kowalski I meant: just copy paste the setup method in your AppTest class to see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't then I don't know why it's not working

Comment: well, its working, but only If I remove the testng @Factory annotation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is provided here, after refactoring and installing a DI framework [Spring Framework and TestNG: unable to pass some parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208025/spring-framework-and-testng-unable-to-pass-some-parameters)