# Do I need a framework in order to use Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have been reading for and practicing dependency injection for the past two days but nothing is working out, and suddenly I found out that there were some frameworks required in order for dependency injection to work.
Is that true?
Isnt it a bad practice to make my project depend on some framework?
Could it be done without the use of a framework?

EDIT: Im new to programming so I dont understand what is the difference between instatiating a class and using its methods (i dont need a framework for that) and using dependency injection and what is better about it

EDIT: Here is an example of me not using a framework and things not working  [TestNG @Factory annotation + not enough knowledge on Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183894/testng-factory-annotation-not-enough-knowledge-on-dependency-injection)

Comment: I think you should use spring framework.

Comment: but do I MUST use a framework?

Comment: Guice is not exactly a framework ... but it is way better than what Spring dependency injection can do.

Comment: Frameworks does not mean "depending on".By using a framework your project does not depend on anything. Frameworks are examples of reusability.And AFAIK you must use framework for DI.

Comment: If you don't use a framework/library, you must implements your own dependecy injection system, which may be boring... I advice you to use Guice too, here is the [getting started](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Using Guice makes sense for me because you can avoid lots of conditional logic when you select what type of implementation to be used in a particular situation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't have to use a framework:

[Dependency Injection](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html)

Of course you can use a framework too, As someone said you can use `Spring Framework` and use their annotations. Here you have a tutorial:

[Dependency Injection with the Spring Framework](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html)

Comment: 2-3 guys above said that I must use a framework. Im confused.

Comment: @J.Kowalski a framework is code that somebody wrote. You can write that code on your own if you think that those libraries that exist are not good for you.

Comment: I dont understand what is the difference between instatiating a class and using its methods (i dont need a framework for that) and using dependency injection and what is better about it.

Comment: Yes, you can use a framework but you don't have to. It simplifies a bit the things. You can read the first article, it is explaining very well what dependency injection means.

Comment: can someone help me out here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183894/testng-factory-annotation-not-enough-knowledge-on-dependency-injection

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use a framework but it will help you write cleaner code. For instance, if you want to inject a mock into a class without using a framework, you need some way to to that either by adding getters/setters, pass it to the constructor or use public variables.

```
public class AClassToTest{
   private A aDependentClass; 

   public void aMethodToTest(){
      int i = aDependentClass.someDependentMethod();
      ..
      ..
   }
}
```

In the above code, `aMethodToTest()` is dependent of what `aDependentClass.someDependentMethod()` returns. This means that you should create a mock of class `A` and mock what `someDependentMethod` returns. This is still possible without using a framework, for example by adding a getter and setter so that you can set the object A in your testclass:

```
@Test
public void testAMethodToTest(){
   //here you must set the object A in your AClassToTest object
   //Create a mock of A with desired values
   //and set it using a setter
}
```

If you for example use spring for dependency injection, it will allow you to set the mock objects in it's IOC container by using it's `@Autowire` notation. Then you do not need to have setters/getters for your mocked objects which will give you cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

For dependency injection **Guice** is great (personal opinion). At least I find it way better than what Spring provides. It is very lightweight too.

https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/